# SubQuery in a CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I have the abstract class **Entity** and these two Entities **Role** and **User** which extends from Entity:

```
@Entity@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected long id = 0; }
    

@Entity
public class Role extends Entity{
    @Column(name = "NAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class User extends Entity{
    @Column(name = "ABBREVIATION", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String abbreviation;

    //The user can have several roles
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "USER_ROLE",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"))
        private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Now when I click on a role, I want the abbreviations of the users to be displayed.
The native query for it is:

```
query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT ABBREVIATION FROM dbtest.user WHERE ID IN"
                        + " (SELECT USER_ID FROM dbtest.user_role WHERE ROLE_ID = " + role.getId() + ")");
```

i have now created a criteria query of it, which always gives me an empty list.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Role> cq = cb.createQuery(Role.class);
Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);

Subquery subquery = cq.subquery(Role.class);
Root subfrom = subquery.from(Role.class);

subquery.select(subfrom.get(Role_.id));
subquery.where(cb.equal(subfrom.get(Role_.id), role.getId()));

cq.multiselect(root.get(User_.abbreviation));
cq.where(cb.equal(root.get(User_.id), subquery));

query = em.createQuery(cq);
return query.getResultList();
```

What is here wrong? Can anyone help ?

Comment: Did you check the `actual query` created in the log ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Jes, i get this: select new entities.Role(generatedAlias0.abbreviation) from User as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.id=(select generatedAlias1.id from Role as generatedAlias1 where generatedAlias1.id=12L)

Comment: Look at your subquery. It generates useless query like this `"SELECT ROLE_ID FROM user_role WHERE ROLE_ID = " + role.getId()`. So it returns `role.getId()` value. You have to select **USER_ID** in the subquery, but your entity does not contain such field. I have stated it in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, set the correct types:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
//CriteriaQuery<Role> cq = cb.createQuery(Role.class);
//The type of the data returned in multiselect.
CriteriaQuery<String> cq = cb.createQuery(String.class);
Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);
//Add to compare
Join<User,Role> joinRole = root.join(User_.roles,JoinType.Inner);

//The type of the data returned in select.
//Subquery subquery = cq.subquery(Role.class);
Subquery<Long> subquery = cq.subquery(Long.class);
//Root subfrom = subquery.from(Role.class);
//We set the data type in the Root
Root<Role> subfrom = subquery.from(Role.class);

subquery.select(subfrom.get(Role_.id));
subquery.where(cb.equal(subfrom.get(Role_.id), role.getId()));

cq.multiselect(root.get(User_.abbreviation));
//cq.where(cb.equal(root.get(User_.id), subquery));
//To use in the where subquery, call the getSelection () method
cq.where(cb.equal(root.get(User_.id), subquery.getSelection()));

query = em.createQuery(cq);
return query.getResultList();
```

Also, the where of the main query is an in not an equals, change this

```
cq.where(cb.equal(root.get(User_.id), subquery.getSelection()));
```

by this

```
cq.where(joinRole.get(Role_.id).in(subquery.getSelection()));
```

Comment: thanks, i get this query : select new java.lang.String(generatedAlias0.abbreviation) from User as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.id in ((select generatedAlias1.id from Role as generatedAlias1 where generatedAlias1.id=12L))
The query hibernate generates is not the same, i need the user_id from user_role table, in this query i get in the second select the role_id from role

Comment: I edit my code, create Join in main query and change cq.where to cq.where(joinRole.get(Role_.id).in(subquery.getSelection()));

Answer (score 1):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Role> cq = cb.createQuery(Role.class);
Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);

Subquery<Long> subquery = cq.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Role> subqueryRoot = subquery.from(Role.class);
Predicate subqueryPredicate = 
        cb.equal(subqueryRoot.get(Role_.id), role.getId());

//!!! I suspect here you have to select USER_ID, but Role entity does not contain such field        
subquery.select(subqueryRoot.get(Role_.id)) 
        .where(subqueryPredicate); 

Predicate queryPredicate = cb.in(root.get(User_.id)).value(subquery); 
cq.multiselect(root.get(User_.abbreviation)).where(queryPredicate);
```